# Moving from LTspice to Ngspice

Tags: ltspice, linux, ngspice, windows

I wrote a `python` script that automatically generates and runs `LTspice` netlists. It runs perfectly on both Windows and Mac. Few of my friends, with whom I am working on this school project, have Linux. This makes it hard for us to run the same `python` script, since they cannot have `LTspice` ([Reference](https://www.pcsuggest.com/install-ltspice-linux/)). I read that `Ngspice` runs perfectly on the three os, however, I am still finding it a bit hard to convert all the `LTspice` Netlists to `Ngspice` ones... I will basically have to rewrite my entire script. Is there a workaround (apart from using WINE)?

Comment: If you only need to use the netlists, what does that have to do with Wine? LTspice runs very well on Wine, so whatever netlists you export will be able to be run just like in Windows. Do you mean that the people having their flavour of Linux can't or are unable to run Wine?

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen Because running the netlist in batch mode requires LTspice executable. I use the following `python` command `subprocess.run([ltspice_executable,-b',netlist])` which will not run in Linux. No, I am saying that my friends cannot use WINE since they do not have administrator rights.

Comment: It looks like your command needs three arguments: executable, command line switches, and filename. Instead of `ltspice_executable` you could use `wine`,instead of `-b` you can use `/path/to/XVIIx64.exe -b`, and the filename remains the same. The part with  admin rights and Wine is confusing. They can;t install Wine on their own computers?

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen Sorry, I did not see the notification. My friends who are on Linux do not have computers so they use the university's...