# Run Ngspice in batch mode or with Python

Tags: ltspice, python, ngspice

For circuit simulations I have mostly been using LTpice, where the netlist is generated automatically with a Python script I wrote and run using the following Python command:
`subprocess.run([ltspice_executable, -b, my_netlist])`(1).

The voltages of my circuit are extracted by reading the generated raw files using the Python package: ltspice.

Now I have to move to Ngspice (@Related question with no answers [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/549526/moving-from-ltspice-to-ngspice?noredirect=1#comment1431107_549526)). My LTspice netlist only contains resistors inductors and capacitors so it could basically run in Ngspice with no problem whatsoever.

I would like to know if there is a similar Python command to the one I use in LTspice (expression(1)) to run Ngspice from my Python script and extract my voltages?

Comment: According to the [manual](http://ngspice.sourceforge.net/docs/ngspice-manual.pdf) (16.8) it says `-b` is batch mode. I haven't used it, but you're welcome to try.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen will check it out. Thank you!

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen It worked very well thank you again !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following @aconcernedcitizen's comment, the command to be used in order to run `Ngspice` in batch mode from `python` is the following:
`subprocess.run([path_to_ngspice_executable,'-r','rawfile.raw','-b','-i',my_netlist])`.

Where rawfile.raw here will contain all the voltages distributions and is supposed to be read to extract the voltage distribution. For `LTspice` the `ltspice` python package see [here](https://pypi.org/project/ltspice/), whereas for `Ngspice` raw files I am still trying to figure it out...